# How to create a tube from a shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, text, effects, path-effects

I have a text which is similar to this font:

[image: October Font image]

Font link: http://www.dafont.com/october-twilight.font

I'm trying to create a text effect with the shape similar in curves to the font above. Here's what I need to create.

[image: font image]

I have GIMP, and photoshop installed, and need to know if I can create it with either of the two or maybe some different software.

Could be tubes, preferably plastic tubes, with some width to the tubes, although thin tubes.

Thanks!

Comment: You do understand that for the effect below the fonts width has to be uniform. Your better of using a vector graphics application,

Comment: Vector Graphics? Any way how to create that effect for the image above in Inkscape?

Answer (score 1):

This is not practical in Photoshop or other raster image programs. Illustrator gives some results easily:

[image]

1. The original text
2. Outlined, fill removed, added thin stroke and added 2 offset paths; The lower row is not united to one shape => not full-length lines
3. Outlined, stretched the characters to overlap, United to one shape, removed fill, added thin stroke, added 2 offset paths